# Deleting the first element of a python list in time complexity O(1) , without using predefined list functions

Tags: python, list, time-complexity

I want to delete the first element of a list (`l[0]`) at constant time. I was wondering if `del l[0]` would do it! If not, is there any other way?

Comment: Do you have a specific problem you’re trying to solve? In CPython, `del` on a list element is O(n), and any other operation that would remove the first element is O(k) or O(n) if you’re talking about any arbitrary list.

Comment: The problem is to write the dequeue function, without using any predefined list functions. Say I have [1,3,5,6]. I want to dequeue the list (make it [3,5,6]), and add a space in the end ([3,5,6,None]), in order to enable enqueue later. I want to do all of this in constant time O(1).

Comment: Sounds like you’re trying to implement a double ended queue. You could make your enqueue/dequeue operations work in O(1) if you use a Python list like a ring buffer (so you wouldn’t be removing elements, you’d instead be changing references/altering where the “beginning” and “end” are.

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways to delete the first element of a list :

```
l = l[1:]
or 
l.pop(0)
or 
del l[0]
```

Comment: None of these are constant time operations, which is what the question is asking about.

Comment: Sorry @wkl I didn't read the title carefully, your question is much deeper, I think slicing will do the job, I found this document https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt, I hope that helped you

Comment: I didn’t ask the question, but slicing in Python creates a new list with shallow copies of the sliced elements, so removing the the first element via slicing of a list of len n would make it an O(n) operation (due to the copying process).

Comment: All three methods are O(n) time complexity.